# В чём заключается ошибка в двумерном массиве?

Tags: c++

Нужно записать каждую строчку в отдельный элемент массива C++. Вот код:

```
char* sentence = new char[N];
char** sentences_1 = new char*[N];
int i = 0;
while (fgets(sentence, N, file) != NULL) {
      sentences_1[i] = new char[N];
      sentences_1[i] = sentence;
      cout << sentences_1[i];
      i++;
}
cout << endl << endl;
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      cout << sentences_1[k] << endl;
}
```

Выводится следующее:

```
Asdf
Bsdf
Csdf
Lsdf

Lsdf
Lsdf
Lsdf
Lsdf
```

В файле:

```
Asdf
Bsdf
Csdf
Lsdf
```

Объясните почему выводит во втором цыкле последний элемент, хотя в первом всё ок. Может я чего то не понимаю, я новичок)

Comment: замените `sentences_1[i] = sentence` на `std::strcpy(sentences_1[i], sentence)`

Answer (score 2):

```
sentences_1[i] = sentence;
```

Вы присваиваете элементу массива `sentences_1` указатель на строку, а не копируете её. Затем, в цикле, меняете содержимое строки `fgets(sentence, N, file)`.

---

Ва нужно скопировать строку, а не указатель:

```
std::strcpy(sentences_1[i], sentence);
```

Comment: Почему бы тогда сразу не предложить читать в ```sentences_1[i]```, а не делать двойную работу по чтению+копированию?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, если нет требования к конкретно использованию `FILE`, `fgets` и `char*` массива, Вас устроит такой вариант, который еще и выглядит покороче:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define N 3

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    string file[N];
    for (int i = 0; getline(fin, file[i]); i++);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << file[i] << endl;
}
```

Или даже вариант с заранее неизвестным количеством строк в файле:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    vector<string> file;
    string buf;
    while (getline(fin, buf))
        file.push_back(buf);
    for (auto it = file.begin(); it != file.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;
}
```